# DOM Manipulation and selection using jQuery or AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

I started using AngularJS a while ago. I'm loving it - it's a very useful and powerful framework and I have built a couple of web apps already. Very little code, very effective, easy to understand, powerful functionality.. it's all great!

As many other developers, I am used to jQuery a lot as I have been working with it for years. Now I'm not comparing jQuery to AngularJS because I understand that they are supposed to do their own things - AngularJS is a framework, whereas jQuery is a library so it's like comparing a table to a chair.

But I just want to know would be the correct way to manipulate or select DOM in AngularJS? I'll give you an example.

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And let's say I'm using TimelineLite to animate each element on document load. In jQuery, I would have something like this:

```
var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.staggerFrom($('.container').children(),1,{opacity:0},0.5);
```

Now to do the same thing in AngularJS, I thought I would use a directive, and attach it to the .container div. something like this:

```
app.directive('beautifulLoad',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var tl = new TimelineLite();                
            var elms = element.children();
            tl.staggerFrom(elms,2,{opacity:0},0.25);
        }
    }
})

<div class="container" beautiful-load>
```

Would this be a right approach?

What if I wanted to create separate animations for each element inside the .container div? In jQuery I would use a selector like this:

```
$('.container h1')
```

but can I not do the same thing in angularJS? So can I not have the following directive instead?

```
app.directive('beautifulLoad',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var tl = new TimelineLite();                
            tl.staggerFrom($(element).find('h1'),2,{opacity:0},0.25);
        }
    }
})
```

Basically what I'm trying to ask is - is it a bad approach to use jQuery inside AngularJS directives and controllers in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you can avoid jQuery:

```
app.directive('beautifulLoad',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var tl = new TimelineLite();                
            tl.staggerFrom(element.find('h1'),2,{opacity:0},0.25);
        }
    }
})
```

If you can avoid jQuery, you should. With AngularJS, it is rarely ever truly needed, and there are usually other, better ways of doing the same thing with jQLite, or with plain old javascript.  You should also limit DOM manipulation to your directive's link function.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know :)